# How do I see post views in phpbb?

Tags: view, count, counter, phpbb, phpbb3

I thought I remembered PHPBB having the ability for viewers to see number of post views for a particular forum. How do I see this?

I have the latest phpbb 3.1.0 installed an haven't done any hacks to it.

Comment: Apparently I can only view forum posts views, not whole forum views in Category view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link is the closest you can get to what you want.
You can always put in a mod request to make the mod or jump on this mod's discussion board and ask the mod author nicely to include those stats. :)

[phpbb_statistics](http://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/mod/phpbb_statistics/)